# UI Component Name

Tags: android

I am newbie in android development. I want to implement the Swipe fetcher like that is in play store to browse category like To Free,Top Paid, New Top Free. By swiping, the page will change but header of previous page is also visible with current page and next page.

Is it a gallery? or any custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ViewPager.
That's what they use in the Play Store.
Its inside the compatibility package.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html